How to reload a tcl theme?
I am making a ttk theme creator, so I need to reload the theme when some internal changes are made in the tcl file.
How can I reload the whole theme?
self.style = ttk.Style(self)
self.tk.call("source", "my_theme.tcl")
self.style.theme_use("my_theme")

Simply using self.style.theme_use("my_theme") doesn't reload the file or changes, and
using self.tk.call("source", "my_theme.tcl") again gives this error:
_tkinter.TclError: Theme my_theme already exists

Is there any way to remove the theme from the tk.call?
